# How does one say "suit yourself" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

The idiom "suit yourself" in English means something like *feel free to [do something] your way, if you don't want to do it mine*, with a slight disapproval directed towards the other person's way. Is there a short way to express this in Esperanto?

Answer (score 9):

Ekzistas pluraj ebloj laŭ mi:

- Agu laŭplaĉe
- Faru laŭ via volo
- Agu kiel vi volas
- Faru kion vi volas

Krome en https://tatoeba.org/epo/sentences/show/240697 vi trovos dekon da aliaj formoj. Esperanto estas riĉa lingvo!

Answer (score 6):

Senhezite mi respondas: "laŭ via plaĉo".

Jen kelkaj alternativoj el la Tekstaro:

- laŭ via volo
- laŭ via prefero
- laŭ via deziro

Answer (score 3):

From: http://dictionaryq.com/esperanto/ - "laŭ via volo" estas "as you wish".